# How to find bandwidth usage/bytes transmitted/received within a certain time frame

Tags: linux, networking, bandwidth, ifconfig

I'm looking for a way to get numbers on bandwidth usage of an eth port. But I need to filter the results to only show me numbers for the last 24 hours. Or any time period in hours or minutes. Just something other than reading off what ifconfig says and /proc/net/dev. I know these are totals since the last reboot. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [IPTraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/)?

To measure bandwidth for a specific interface over a period of 24 hours you could try something like this:

```
iptraf -d eth1 -B -L /tmp/iptraf.log -t 1440
```

This will generate a report like this

```
Total:  307 packets, 67553 bytes
        (incoming: 167 packets, 46093 bytes; outgoing: 140 packets, 21460 bytes)
IP:     307 packets, 63237 bytes
        (incoming: 167 packets, 43737 bytes; outgoing: 140 packets, 19500 bytes)
TCP: 288 packets, 59678 bytes
        (incoming: 156 packets, 40861 bytes; outgoing: 132 packets, 18817 bytes)
UDP: 9 packets, 2719 bytes
        (incoming: 6 packets, 2456 bytes; outgoing: 3 packets, 263 bytes)
ICMP: 10 packets, 840 bytes
        (incoming: 5 packets, 420 bytes; outgoing: 5 packets, 420 bytes)
Other IP: 0 packets, 0 bytes
        (incoming: 0 packets, 0 bytes; outgoing: 0 packets, 0 bytes)
Non-IP: 0 packets, 0 bytes
        (incoming: 0 packets, 0 bytes; outgoing: 0 packets, 0 bytes)
Broadcast: 3 packets, 1770 bytes

Average rates:
  Total:        9.00 kbits/s, 5.12 packets/s
  Incoming:     6.13 kbits/s, 2.78 packets/s
  Outgoing:     2.85 kbits/s, 2.33 packets/s

Peak total activity: 26.27 kbits/s, 11.40 packets/s
Peak incoming rate: 17.85 kbits/s, 6.20 packets/s
Peak outgoing rate: 8.41 kbits/s, 5.80 packets/s

IP checksum errors: 0
```